# Visual Basic For Applications: Problem with table editing through textbox

Tags: excel, vba, function, textbox, inventory-management

I have been running with this problem for a while, I leave the sample file code, written below, the thing is that when I run it on the computer from where I work at, in the Sub CommandButton1_Click() when it starts to run the 3 lines after the commented line with i=1, each line starts the ListBox1_Click() and resets the textbox values making a mess, how I overcome this?, by using a conditional so it doesn't overwrite anything when working in other functions.

I want to know if anyone had before this problem, and know how to fix it. Running it from my personal computer is not an option, but the if conditional makes the thing, however I don't think is the optimal way to solve the problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Ultima_Fila As Integer
    Ultima_Fila = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2") + 1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Ultima_Fila).EntireRow.Insert
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Ultima_Fila) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
    'i=1 'Required i to be 1 in order to avoid the code to jump and read the textbox from the ListBox1_Click
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Ultima_Fila) = TextBox1.Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Ultima_Fila) = TextBox2.Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Ultima_Fila) = TextBox3.Value
    'i=0 Restarts i value
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    'If i = 0 Then 'When the sub is initialized directly from the listbox click it stores the values displayed on the textboxes
        TextBox1 = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
        TextBox2 = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
        TextBox3 = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
    'End If 'This conditional jumps the following instruction when it is reached from the CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .RowSource = "Table1"
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are calling the `ListBox1_Click()` event on the problem line. Are you doing this for a reason?

Comment: My bad it was just part of the comment

Comment: Is your code still jumping into the `ListBox1_Click()` event?

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents=False` disables application events. Events won't trigger any event procedures while this property is Not True. There is no equivalent to `EnableEvents` in *Word*, for example, and the Application's (Excel's) events are different from the events of ActiveX controls. The method you found is the one recommended in all those cases. The only difference between the recommendation and your solution is that the variable should be named meaningfully and it should be a Boolean to better simulate Excel's `EnableEvents` property.

Comment: @ Samuel Everson without the conditional, in my laptop from where I work, yes is jumping into the ListBox1_Click()

Comment: @Variatus, I will try what you say, it sounds better, however for me is still a mystery why can my personal laptop run it without specifying not to jump to other events while being in the button click event., despite using Excel version 16.0.14026.20270 in both, I thought maybe my personal computer could have other setting that is not explicit in code, that somehow disables the event jump.

Comment: FWIW I was unable to recreate the issue, it's rather odd.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't be disheartened by the changes I made to your code. In essence it remains the same. I just wanted to be sure that what I tell you is 100% correct:-

The ListBox1_Click event is triggered by a change to `ListBox1.ListIndex`. My code below contains such a change and disables the event it causes in the way you already found. The explanation for the procedure being fired on another computer is that the ListIndex is changed. Perhaps the code being run there is different and perhaps it's a Mac or Google sheets, in short, a non-Microsoft engine interpreting the same code.

However, you may still like my code because it has some features that yours didn't have. Please try it. It should run on both systems.

```
Option Explicit

Private DisableListBoxEvents    As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ' 263
    
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .RowSource = "Table1"
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 263

    Dim Ultima_Fila As Integer
    Dim Tbx         As Control
    Dim i           As Integer
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Ultima_Fila = .Range("E2").Value + 1
        With .ListObjects(1)
            ' inserts a table row before table row Ultima_Fila
            ' Omit the number to append a row.
            ' To convert sheet row to table row enable this line:-
```

'               Ultima_Fila = Ultima_Fila - .Range.Row - 1
With .ListRows.Add(Ultima_Fila).Range
For i = 1 To 3
Set Tbx = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
.Cells(i + 1).Value = Tbx.Value
Tbx.Value = ""
Next i
End With
End With
End With

```
    With ListBox1
        DisableListBoxEvents = True
        .RowSource = "Table1"
        .ListIndex = -1
        DisableListBoxEvents = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    ' 263
    
    Dim i       As Integer
    
    If DisableListBoxEvents Then Exit Sub
    With ListBox1
        For i = 1 To 3
            Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = .List(.ListIndex, i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, what does .ListObjects(1) object refers to?

Comment: A `ListObject` is a *table*. `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` is the first table on *ActiveSheet*. `ListObjects(1).Range` is the range of the entire table. `ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange` excludes headers and totals and is equal to `Range("Table1")` in your workbook but it is bad practice to refer to the same object by different names in the same code.  `Range("Table1")` would be appropriate if you have referred to the tables as `ListObjects("Table1")`. Your original code doesn't make transparent that `Range("Table1") is, in fact, a table's range.